# Harnessed by the 6th day

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am the redeemer, the primal desire
>
> I destroy what I can, yet in such I can heal.
>
> I tear down all I touch, yet lift up the flier
>
> I'm the servant of men, yet commander of steel.

What am I?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a riddle with the same answer and many of the same clues here before. But search turned up nothing. Maybe it's just deja vu.

Comment: If there is, it is a coincidence. Which isn't very unlikely, considering how easy it is to make a riddle out of fire

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> Fire?

I am the redeemer, the primal desire

> Cavemen+fire

I destroy what I can, yet in such I can heal.

> It burns what it touches but you can use it to cauterize wounds.

I tear down all I touch, yet lift up the flier

> Forest fires or hot air balloons

I'm the servant of men, yet commander of steel.

> You can forge steel in fire, but people make fire for their own purpose.

Comment: Nicely done, as always. I was also thinking cauterization for the "healing" part

Comment: Is it just me... or was that riddle awfully.... easy? ;)